# "execute" function in Job Java Quartz returns a value?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

The "execute" function in `Job` interface in Quartz library is defined as:

```
 @Override
 public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
   throws JobExecutionException {
  // do job
 }
```

However, I'm calling a service function that would return a response as a `String`. How would I do that so that the `execute` function would return a String so I can pass it back to the caller?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here. Normally the job would be executed by a scheduler (Quartz) and a scheduler would not know what to do with a return value. If you want to run a job asynchronously you could return a Future but I'm not sure Quartz supports this - the built-in ScheduledExecutorService would.

Comment: A Quartz job can produce and save a job execution result in the JobExecutionContext. If you need to read/process the result, you can implement Quartz JobListener and in its jobWasExecuted method, you can do whatever you want with the result. Please note that Quartz jobs are executed asynchronously by Quartz as described by Thomas, so you do not "call a job and wait for the job execution to finish and return a result". Rather you can be notified when the job execution finishes and then you can obtain the result.